# How to make the top row of a Bootstrap grid fill the entire screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullscreen

A common, modern design technique for responsive websites is to use a screen-height element as the above-the-fold content wrapper, and have all other content available below. **[Here's a good discussion](https://www.html5andbeyond.com/fullscreen-website-design-100-window-height-div/)** on this technique. Here's **[a demo at CodePen](http://codepen.io/html5andblog/full/aFsBo/)**:

```
#fullscreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#fullscreen .fullscreen-content {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<div id="fullscreen">
    <div class="fullscreen-content">
    ... 
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make a Bootstrap 3 row behave in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing this challenge. Here's my current solution.

```
.full-ht {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.full-ht-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row full-ht">
        <div lass="col-xs-12 full-ht">                
            <div id="page-top-content" class="full-ht-content">
                 Above-the-fold content.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            Other content.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/xr4y6dzy/)**